# Counting Characters in a String in Swift with Loop

Tags: swift, loops, for-loop

I'm trying to loop through a string and count its characters in Swift. This code successfully outputs the character count, but I receive this warning:

> warning: immutable value 'character' was never used; consider
>   replacing with '_' or removing it for character in quote {
>       ^~~~~~~~~
>       _

This is my code:

```
var quote = "hello there"
var count = 0

for character in quote {
  count = count + 1
}
print("\(count)")
```

Does anyone know why I have this warning? Also, is this the best way to approach this task? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Please **read** the error message carefully, it tells you precisely what's wrong and what you can do.

> immutable value 'character' was never used

That's indeed true, the variable `character` is unused. The compiler provides  two fixes:

> consider replacing with '_' or removing it

The latter is not an option in a loop, so use the first, replace `character` with an underscore

```
for _ in quote {
```